Has the US considered or offered selling TLAMs (cruise missiles) to Taiwan?
Taiwan appears to have developed their own indigenous cruise missiles. Has the US considered/offered to sell them some US-made ones, or was that considered too escalatory towards China?
That seems likely, but not the only possibility, e.g. some Taiwanese retired admiral said that the US tried to hinder domestic development of Taiwanese anti-ship missiles (by denying them some component sales) in order to sell Taiwan equivalent US missiles.

"Has the US considered...." - I'm quite sure that discussion has come about more than once. Why they have not is probably not discoverable from out here.

I asked about TLAMs because I could recall they had 'record sales' recently, with both Japan and Australia buying them by the hundreds.

No idea [yet] about TLAMs as such, but they seem to have received approval at least for shorter range cruise missiles (SLAM-ER) (range "in excess" of 250km), although these are "backlogged" currently, and the Taiwanese side has also shown interest in buying (more stealthy) JASSMs (range > 370km), but [as of Dec 2023] the US has yet to give a "clear response" on the latter, according to one Taiwanese legislator.
